# jquery fade() not fading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ADINIDI/5/) prototype, with two menu items that show a **sub-menu on click**:

[image: screenshot of jsbin]

The visibility of the sub-menus is controlled by `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut`. However, the opacity doesn't animate. It just waits the specified time, and then completely appears or completely hides. No fading.

The code is pretty straightforward, so I'm pretty puzzled...

```
(function(){
  var activeMenu = null;
  var animation = {
    duration: 250,
    queue: true
  };
  $(document).click(function(){
    if(activeMenu) {
      $(activeMenu).removeClass('active-nav-item');
      $(activeMenu).find('.nav-group').fadeOut(animation);
      activeMenu = null;
    }
  });
  $.fn.simpleMenu = function() {
    $(this).children('.nav-item:has(.nav-group)').each(function(i,e) {
      $(e).click(function() {
        if(activeMenu) {
          $(activeMenu).removeClass('active-nav-item');
          $(activeMenu).find('.nav-group').fadeOut(animation);
        }
        if(activeMenu !== e) {
          activeMenu = e;
          $(activeMenu).addClass('active-nav-item');
          $(activeMenu).find('.nav-group').fadeIn(animation);
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
  };
})();

$('.global-nav').simpleMenu();
$('.meta-nav').simpleMenu();
```

Comment: It must be your CSS. I added a `p` tag and it didn't fade out, but simply disappeared. After blanking your CSS, it faded like normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is your problem line:

```
* {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Upon removing this and not changing anything else, it works as expected.

http://jsbin.com/ADINIDI/7